# Weaker Convergence = Larger Completion?

Tags: general-topology

First, I know that the weaker the topology, the larger the closure of a given subset.  (This is because in a weaker topology, the closed sets are harder to find, so we have to settle for a larger one.)

Second, I know that specifying the convergence and specifying the topology give the same amount of information on the topology.

As such, my question is, is there an analogous statement that say e.g. "the weaker the convergence, the larger the completion"?

For example, $L^\infty$ is a stronger convergence criterion than $L^2$ convergence, and indeed the completion of $C(0,1)$ is smaller in the former.

Comment: You need to be careful because convergence of sequences alone does not determine a topology (it does if it is first countable I think and most certainly metric spaces like the examples you gave) you need in general to know how all nets converge.

Comment: Yes, you're right.  I had convergence of nets in mind but didn't specify.  Thanks for the reminder!